# How to detect changes in formula field value via API?

Tags: api, data-synchronization

I've been stumped on this issue for a while now.

I have a system which polls Salesforce for updates to records, based on LastModified timestamp (or [getUpdated()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_getupdated.htm)). Updated records get synched down to the target system whenever they're updated in Salesforce. However, this fails for formula fields, whose values can change at any time without affecting the record.

I've implemented a brute-force method of re-synching every single record, but this is a poor solution for obvious reasons.

I've also tried re-creating the formula in my target system, but this also ends up being a poor solution.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formula fields are not stored within Salesforce. These values are generated on the fly. So each time you request the record, that value is recalculated. If you are using formula fields to pull down a parent's record value for example, you have to update their associated children record so you can properly queue them for the getUpdated Method()